# Subsetting and repetition of rows in a dataframe using R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose we have the following data with column names "id", "time" and "x":

```
df<-
structure(
list(
id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
time = c(20L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 13L, 2L, 6L),
x = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)
),
.Names = c("id", "time", "x"),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-7L)
)
```

Each id has multiple observations for time and x. I want to extract the last observation for each id and form a new dataframe which repeats these observations according to the number of observations per each id in the original data. I am able to extract the last observations for each id using the following codes

```
library(dplyr) 
df<-df%>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
filter( ((x)==0 & row_number()==n())| ((x)==1 & row_number()==n()))
```

What is left unresolved is the repetition aspect. The expected output would look like

```
df <-
structure(
list(
id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
time = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 13L, 13L, 6L, 6L),
x = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)
),
.Names = c("id", "time", "x"),
class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA,-7L)
)
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Thanks, all the answers work well for my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `ave` to find the `max` row number for each `ID` and subset it from the data frame.

```
df[ave(1:nrow(df), df$id, FUN = max), ]

#    id time x
#3    1    7 0
#3.1  1    7 0
#3.2  1    7 0
#5    2   13 1
#5.1  2   13 1
#7    3    6 0
#7.1  3    6 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `last()` to grab the last row within each id.

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(time = last(time),
           x = last(x))
```

Because `last(x)` returns a single value, it gets expanded out to fill all the rows in the `mutate()` call.

This can also be applied to an arbitrary number of variables using `mutate_at`:

```
df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate_at(vars(-id), ~ last(.))
```

Comment: Clever, but now do it when you have 30 variables in `df` :-)

Comment: @thelatemail OK :-)

Comment: Or `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(last))
`

Comment: @Marius - :-D !

Answer (score 2):

`slice` will be your friend in the tidyverse I reckon:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(rep(n(),n()))
## A tibble: 7 x 3
## Groups:   id [3]
#     id  time     x
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     7     0
#2     1     7     0
#3     1     7     0
#4     2    13     1
#5     2    13     1
#6     3     6     0
#7     3     6     0
```

In `data.table`, you could also use the `mult=` argument of a join:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[df[,.(id)], on="id", mult="last"]
#   id time x
#1:  1    7 0
#2:  1    7 0
#3:  1    7 0
#4:  2   13 1
#5:  2   13 1
#6:  3    6 0
#7:  3    6 0
```

And in base R, a `merge` will get you there too:

```
merge(df["id"], df[!duplicated(df$id, fromLast=TRUE),])
#  id time x
#1  1    7 0
#2  1    7 0
#3  1    7 0
#4  2   13 1
#5  2   13 1
#6  3    6 0
#7  3    6 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table` you can try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,.(time=rep(time[.N],.N), x=rep(x[.N],.N)), by=id]
   id time  x
1:  1    7  0
2:  1    7  0
3:  1    7  0
4:  2   13  1
5:  2   13  1
6:  3    6  0
7:  3    6  0
```

Following @thelatemai, to avoid name the columns you can also try

```
df[, .SD[rep(.N,.N)], by=id]
   id time x
1:  1    7 0
2:  1    7 0
3:  1    7 0
4:  2   13 1
5:  2   13 1
6:  3    6 0
7:  3    6 0
```

Comment: You could avoid all the column naming if you just subset the whole sub-dataframe like `df[, .SD[rep(.N,.N)], by=id]` , though that might not be super efficient. I'm sure you could do some trickery with the `.I` row counter too if you were keen.

Comment: @thelatemail Your variant is great, I include in the answer.